# How to run a loop on a query that gives the sum of time remaining on tickets so that we get time remaining of individual tickets?

Tags: sql, loops

I have a table consisting of Entity_Id, Date_of_Modification, Previous_State, and New_State for tickets we are working on.

| Entity_Id | Date_of_Modification | Previous_State | New_State | Time Difference (Days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/18/2020 | Internal Review | Done | 0 |
| 1 | 3/18/2020 | Open | Internal Review | 0 |
| 2 | 6/25/2020 | Internal Review | Done | 1 |
| 2 | 6/24/2020 | Done | Internal Review | 0 |
| 2 | 6/21/2020 | Testing | Done | 3 |
| 2 | 6/18/2020 | In Dev | Testing | 3 |
| 2 | 4/30/2020 | Planned | In Dev | 49 |
| 2 | 3/21/2020 | Open | Planned | 0 |
| 3 | 3/31/2020 | Internal Review | Internal Review | 6 |
| 3 | 3/25/2020 | Analyzing | Internal Review | 5 |
| 3 | 3/20/2020 | Analyzing | Analyzing | 1 |
| 3 | 3/10/2020 | Open | Analyzing | 0 |
| 4 | 3/25/2020 | Internal Review | Done | 2 |
| 4 | 3/23/2020 | Internal Review | Internal Review | 0 |
| 4 | 3/23/2020 | Open | Internal Review | 5 |
| 4 | 3/18/2020 | Open | Open | 32 |
| 4 | 3/18/2020 | Done | Open | 0 |
| 4 | 2/14/2020 | Done | Done | 17 |
| 4 | 2/14/2020 | Internal Review | Done | 0 |
| 4 | 1/28/2020 | Internal Review | Internal Review | 2 |
| 4 | 1/28/2020 | Open | Internal Review | 0 |

I have figured out the query for calculating the total amount of time already spent by a ticket. 
I also have figured out the time spent by the ticket on 'internal review' state because we want the time spent apart from this state and have written a query to calculate the remaining time. 
-------query to find total time remaining for a ticket apart from internal review---------

```
 SELECT M.TotalTime - N.IRTotalTime AS RemainingHours
    FROM
```

----------query to find total time spent on a ticket---------

```
(SELECT SUM(B.Diff) AS TotalTime
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            A.Modification_Id,
            A.Date_of_Modification, 
            A.Previous_State, 
            A.State AS NewState, 
            DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(Date_of_Modification) OVER (ORDER BY Date_of_Modification), Date_of_Modification)
                AS Diff
            FROM 
                (SELECT 
                    Modification_Id,
                    Date_of_Modification, 
                    Previous_State, 
                    State 
                FROM Book2 
                )AS A)
            AS B) AS M
    ,
```

----------query to find total time spent on internal review---------

```
(SELECT SUM(B.Diff) AS IRTotalTime
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            A.Modification_Id,
            A.Date_of_Modification, 
            A.Previous_State, 
            A.State AS NewState,    
            DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(Date_of_Modification) OVER (ORDER BY Date_of_Modification), Date_of_Modification) AS Diff  
            FROM 
                (SELECT 
                    Modification_Id,
                    Date_of_Modification, 
                    Previous_State, 
                    State 
                FROM Book2
                    WHERE Previous_State = 'Internal Review' AND State <> 'Internal Review'

                    UNION 

                SELECT 
                    Modification_Id,
                    Date_of_Modification, 
                    Previous_State, 
                    State
                FROM Book2
                    WHERE Previous_State = 'Internal Review' AND State = 'Internal Review'
                ) AS A 
            ) AS B 
        WHERE B.Previous_State = 'Internal Review' AND B.NewState <> 'Internal Review') AS N
```

But this query for some reason is only for for case when I specify the ticket number (i.e. Entity_Id). It is not working when I run it over the entire table. So I thought if we could use a loop to get the total remaining time of individual tickets.
But I am having difficulty running that query through a loop and getting the Entity_Id displayed for each calculation on the tickets.

When I run the query I get the value 55 which might be the total remaining time. But I want the total remaining time for individual tickets like:

| Entity_Id | Remaining Time (Days) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 95 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 4 | 20 |

Thank you

Update:
I used `PARTITION BY Entity_Id` and got the required total time and Internal Review time of individual tickets and saved the result in separate tables. 
 I now need to subtract the value of time of 2nd table from 1st table. There are rows that have NULL value in the time spent column in some of the rows of both the table.

Table A (Total time spent):

| Entity_Id | Remaining Time (Days) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 96 |
| 3 | 21 |
| 4 | 21 |

Table A (Time spent in Internal Review):

| Entity_Id | Remaining Time (Days) |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 4 | 5 |

Thanks

**Update**:

I have figured out the query for it. Thank you all for your suggestions.
If the question regarding the Internal review state was unclear, here is a diag representing what I require from this query for a particular ticket:

Total: sum of time diff = 58 days 
Internal Review State: 19 days 
Final result: 39 days

[image]

@JonArmstrong

Comment: The table you show contains only data related to "Internal Review".   Can you add the other data to the question?  Isn't it tough to calculate a difference or total time if all the data isn't present?  I suspect there are other problems, not just the one you noticed with a limited set of data.  The direct answer to your question is `GROUP BY`, but that may not be sufficient.

Comment: @JonArmstrong I have updated the question as per your request. Could you write your answer based on the data and the query provided by me?

Comment: You still seem to be missing data, the entry which has `new_state = 'Open'` for `entity = 3`.  Are you suggesting the time in the 'Open' state can be ignored?  Also, you have one row which has `prev_state = 'Internal Review'` and `new_state = 'Open'`.  Does that represent a transition to a state where time should again be ignored, similar to 'Idle'?

Comment: I have updated the data. The transition time from Internal review to any other state should be considered. That's it. And that time should be subtracted from the total time of the ticket. @JonArmstrong

Comment: I have added more details to the question and data update for Entity_Id 4 if you would want to look into it. @JonArmstrong

Comment: With your new data, I obtained 58 as the total time for entity 4, and Internal Review of 4, leaving a Remaining time of 54.  That's with the current answer.  Is that correct?

Comment: Btw, your data is wrong.  You can't have a prev_state of Internal Review when the previous entry has a new state of Done.  That was partially why I asked for clarification originally.  Some of your data was missing or you had odd requirements about previous states not always matching the actual previous entry for that entity.  For that reason, you can't add 17 to Internal Review since during that time we were not in Internal Review.  The new_state drives that, not the mistaken prev_state of the next row.  Either change the new_state of RowN or the prev_state of rowN+1.

Comment: and you have an ordering/logic issue when two rows for the same entity have the same date.  More detail needs to be added to the question to resolve that ambiguity.

Comment: No it is not correct. That is why I showed you the diagram. 1st the transition from Open to IR happens at 1/28 and then it continues until it's state is changed from IR to Done on 2/14 i.e. it stayed in IR for 17 days. Similarly, it changes from Open to IR at 3/23 and then stays in that state up until 3/25 i.e. 2 days. So total State Time= 17+ 2. So now we have to subtract 19 from 58. Also, I have not approved any answer because none has give me the right result. I have figured out a separate way to make it work. The PARTITION BY suggestion did help me though. @JonArmstrong

Comment: Please address the ordering question.  You must provide a way to uniquely order your rows via the data in those rows.  If two rows for the same entity share the same date, there must be other data to resolve the ordering issue.  Which row is first on that same date?

Comment: If new_state / prev_state act like a linked list, that needs to be specified.  This may lead to a different approach.  That linked list represents a kind of data duplication.  Removing that approach actually simplifies the solution.  If there is a date/sequence, we can order uniquely and then easily calculate the next/prev state, without ambiguity and without needing to store that extra state detail.

Comment: How did you decide that (on 2/14) the transition from `Done` to `Done` had anything to do with `Internal Review`?  The prior row (`Internal Review` to `Done`) had a time difference of 0.  That was the last time to add to IR.  The "Done to Done" is something else.  Oh well.  I tried.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `PARTITION BY` in your lag functions, like so:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(Date_of_Modification) OVER (PARTITION BY Entity_Id ORDER BY Date_of_Modification), Date_of_Modification)
```